# NoReverseMatch Error: Reverse for 'episodeshowlinks' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

For some reason that I have not figured out yet, I am getting the following error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://192.168.33.10:8000/podfunnel/episodechaptermarks/54/

Django Version: 1.9
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('producer',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'registration',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'storages',
 'django_extensions',
 'randomslugfield',
 'adminsortable2',
 'crispy_forms')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')



Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/vagrant/fullcast_project/producer/views/pod_funnel.py" in episodechaptermarks
  803.     return render(request, 'pod_funnel/forms_chapter_marks.html', context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  67.             template_name, context, request=request, using=using)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  97.         return template.render(context, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  95.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  206.                     return self._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  988.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  955.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  173.         return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  988.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  955.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  69.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  988.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  955.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  513.                         six.reraise(*exc_info)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  499.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  600.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  508.                              (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /podfunnel/episodechaptermarks/54/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'episodeshowlinks' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'podfunnel/episodeshowlinks/(?P<production_id>[0-9]+)/$']
```

Now, everything was working fine. Input fields were working fine and was posting into the database. Redirection to another template was working good until today. It looks the issue is in my `form_chapter_marks.html` template under `<a class="btn btn-primary box-shadow--6dp" href="{% url 'podfunnel:episodeshowlinks' %}" role="button"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp Next</a>` but don't know why the error is showing now when I was not having problems with it before.

Would appreciate some help here.

Here is my `url` patterns:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

import producer.views.pod_funnel as views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^dashboard/', views.dashboard, name="dashboard"),
    url(r'^clientsetup/', views.ClientSetupView.as_view(), name="clientsetup"),
    url(r'^podcastsetup/', views.PodcastSetupView.as_view(), name="podcastsetup"),
    url(r'^episodeinfo/$', views.EpisodeInfoView.as_view(), name="episodeinfo"),
    url(r'^episodeinfo/(?P<production_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.EpisodeInfoView.as_view(), name="episodeinfo_edit"),
    url(r'^episodeimagefiles/(?P<production_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.EpisodeImageFilesView.as_view(), name="episodeimagefiles"),
    url(r'^episodewordpressinfo/(?P<production_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.EpisodeWordpressInfoView.as_view(), name="episodewordpressinfo"),
    url(r'^episodechaptermarks/(?P<production_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.episodechaptermarks, name="episodechaptermarks"),
    url(r'^episodechaptermarks/(?P<chaptermark_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.episodechaptermarks, name="episodechaptermarks_edit"),
    url(r'^episodeshowlinks/(?P<production_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.episodeshowlinks, name="episodeshowlinks"),
    url(r'^episodeshowlinks/(?P<showlink_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.episodeshowlinks, name="episodeshowlinks_edit"),
    url(r'^episodetweetables/(?P<production_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.episodetweetables, name="episodetweetables"),
    url(r'^episodetweetables/(?P<tweetable_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.episodetweetables, name="episodetweetables_edit"),
    url(r'^episodeclicktotweet/(?P<production_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.episodeclicktotweet, name="episodeclicktotweet"),
    url(r'^episodeclicktotweet/(?P<clicktotweet_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.episodeclicktotweet, name="episodeclicktotweet_edit"),
    url(r'^episodeschedule/(?P<production_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.EpisodeScheduleView.as_view(), name="episodeschedule"),
    url(r'^accounts/', views.AccountsView.as_view(), name="accounts"),
    url(r'^wordpressaccount/', views.WordpressAccountView.as_view(), name="wordpressaccount"),
    url(r'^wordpressaccountsetup/', views.WordpressAccountSetupView.as_view(), name="wordpressaccountsetup"),
    url(r'^wordpressaccountsortable/', views.WordpressAccountSortableView.as_view(), name="wordpressaccountsortable"),
    url(r'^soundcloudaccount/', views.SoundcloudAccountView.as_view(), name="soundcloudaccount"),
    url(r'^soundcloud_auth/', views.SoundcloudAuthenticationView.as_view(), name="soundcloud_auth"),
    url(r'^twitteraccount/', views.TwitterAccountView.as_view(), name="twitteraccount"),
    url(r'^twitter_auth/', views.TwitterAuthenticationView.as_view(), name="twitter_auth"),
]
```

`chaptermarks` and `episodeshowlinks` view in `pod_funnel.py`

```
@login_required
def episodechaptermarks(request, *args, **kwargs):

    initial_values = {}
    user = request.user
    # production_id = request.production_id

    # Lets get client and podcast for the user already. if not existent raise 404
    client, podcast = get_podfunnel_client_and_podcast_for_user(user)
    if client is None or podcast is None:
        raise Http404

    # The production_id or the chaptermark_id must be passed on the kwargs
    production_id = kwargs.get('production_id', None)
    chaptermark_id = kwargs.get('chaptermark_id', None)
    if chaptermark_id is not None:
        chaptermark = get_object_or_404(ChapterMark, id=chaptermark_id)
        production = chaptermark.production
    # else:
    #     chaptermark_id = ChapterMark(id=chaptermark_id)
    elif production_id:
        production = get_object_or_404(Production, id=production_id)
        chaptermark = None

    initial_values['production_id'] = production.id

    if chaptermark is not None:
        initial_values['chaptermark_id'] = chaptermark_id
        initial_values['start_time'] = chaptermark.start_time
        initial_values['title'] = chaptermark.title

    # Create the formset, specifying the form and formset we want to use.
    EpisodeChapterMarksFormSet = formset_factory(EpisodeChapterMarksForm, formset=BaseChapterMarkFormSet)

    # Get our existing chapter mark data for this user.  This is used as initial data.
    chapter_marks = ChapterMark.objects.filter(id=chaptermark_id).order_by('start_time')
    chaptermarks_data = [{'start_time': c.start_time, 'title': c.title}
                    for c in chapter_marks]

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # chaptermarks_form = EpisodeChapterMarksForm(request.POST)
        chaptermarks_formset = EpisodeChapterMarksFormSet(request.POST)

        if chaptermarks_formset.is_valid():

            new_chaptermarks = []

            for chaptermarks_form in chaptermarks_formset:
                production_id = chaptermarks_form.cleaned_data.get('production_id')
                chaptermark_id = chaptermarks_form.cleaned_data.get('chaptermark_id')
                start_time = chaptermarks_form.cleaned_data.get('start_time')
                title = chaptermarks_form.cleaned_data.get('title')

                if chaptermark_id is not None:
                    chaptermark = ChapterMark.objects.get(id=chaptermark_id)
                else:
                    chaptermark = ChapterMark()

                if start_time and title:
                    new_chaptermarks.append(ChapterMark(id=chaptermark_id, start_time=start_time, title=title))

                chaptermark.start_time = start_time
                chaptermark.title = title
                chaptermark.production = production
                chaptermark.save()

    else:
        chapter_marks = ChapterMark(id=chaptermark_id)
        chaptermarks_formset = EpisodeChapterMarksFormSet(initial=chaptermarks_data)

    context = {
        'chapter_marks': chapter_marks,
        'chaptermarks_formset': chaptermarks_formset,
    }

    return render(request, 'pod_funnel/forms_chapter_marks.html', context)
```

**---------------------**

```
@login_required
def episodeshowlinks(request, *args, **kwargs):

    initial_values = {}
    user = request.user
    # production_id = request.production_id

    # Lets get client and podcast for the user already. if not existent raise 404
    client, podcast = get_podfunnel_client_and_podcast_for_user(user)
    if client is None or podcast is None:
        raise Http404

    # The production_id or the showlink_id must be passed on the kwargs
    production_id = kwargs.get('production_id', None)
    showlink_id = kwargs.get('showlink_id', None)
    if showlink_id is not None:
        showlink = get_object_or_404(ProductionLink, id=showlink_id)
        production = showlink.production
    # else:
    #     chaptermark_id = ChapterMark(id=chaptermark_id)
    elif production_id:
        production = get_object_or_404(Production, id=production_id)
        showlink = None

    initial_values['production_id'] = production.id

    if showlink is not None:
        initial_values['showlink_id'] = showlink_id
        initial_values['title'] = showlink.title
        initial_values['url'] = showlink.url

    # Create the formset, specifying the form and formset we want to use.
    EpisodeShowLinksFormSet = formset_factory(EpisodeShowLinksForm, formset=BaseShowLinkFormSet)

    # Get our existing chapter mark data for this user.  This is used as initial data.
    show_links = ProductionLink.objects.filter(id=showlink_id).order_by('title')
    showlinks_data = [{'title': s.title, 'url': s.url}
                         for s in show_links]

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # chaptermarks_form = EpisodeChapterMarksForm(request.POST)
        showlinks_formset = EpisodeShowLinksFormSet(request.POST)

        if showlinks_formset.is_valid():

            new_showlinks = []

            for showlinks_form in showlinks_formset:
                production_id = showlinks_form.cleaned_data.get('production_id')
                showlink_id = showlinks_form.cleaned_data.get('showlink_id')
                title = showlinks_form.cleaned_data.get('title')
                url = showlinks_form.cleaned_data.get('url')

                if showlink_id is not None:
                    showlink = ProductionLink.objects.get(id=showlink_id)
                else:
                    showlink = ProductionLink()

                if title and url:
                    new_showlinks.append(ProductionLink(id=showlink_id, title=title, url=url))

                showlink.title = title
                showlink.url = url
                showlink.production = production
                showlink.save()

    else:
        show_links = ProductionLink(id=showlink_id)
        showlinks_formset = EpisodeShowLinksFormSet(initial=showlinks_data)

    context = {
        'show_links': show_links,
        'showlinks_formset': showlinks_formset,
    }

    return render(request, 'pod_funnel/forms_show_links.html', context)
```

Templates for `chaptermarks` and `showlinks`:

```
{% extends "pod_funnel/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}

<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-success active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 50%">
    <span class="sr-only">50% Complete</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default box-shadow--16dp col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
<div class="panel-body">

<div class='row'>
<div class='col-sm-12'>

<h3>Chapter Marks</h3>

<hr/>

<form method='POST'>
    {% csrf_token %}

{{ chaptermarks_formset.management_form }}

    {% for chaptermarks_form in chaptermarks_formset %}
        <div class="chaptermarks-formset">
            {{ chaptermarks_form.start_time }}

            {{ chaptermarks_form.title }}

        </div>
    {% endfor %}

<hr/>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm box-shadow--6dp">Save</button>
<p>
<p>
<a class="btn btn-primary box-shadow--6dp" href="{% url 'podfunnel:episodeshowlinks' %}" role="button"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp Next</a>

</form>

</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

**---------------**

```
{% extends "pod_funnel/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}

<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-success active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="62.5" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 62.5%">
    <span class="sr-only">62.5% Complete</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default box-shadow--16dp col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
<div class="panel-body">

<div class='row'>
<div class='col-sm-12'>

<h3>Show Links</h3>

<hr/>

<form method='POST'>
    {% csrf_token %}

{{ showlinks_formset.management_form }}

    {% for showlinks_form in showlinks_formset %}
        <div class="showlinks-formset">
            {{ showlinks_form.title }}

            {{ showlinks_form.url }}

        </div>
    {% endfor %}

<hr/>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm box-shadow--6dp">Save</button>
<p>
<p>
<a class="btn btn-primary box-shadow--6dp" href="{% url 'podfunnel:episodetweetables' %}" role="button"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp Next</a>

</form>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you've showed all the rest of that code; the URLs and the template fragment are enough.

In the fragment you quote, you show that you are calling `{% url 'podfunnel:episodeshowlinks' %}`. But your URLs - and the error message - show that the only pattern with the name `episodeshowlinks` is expecting an argument: `production_id`. You need to pass that in to the url tag so it knows what URL to generate.

Note that generally your URLs seem very broken; I can't understand why you have for instance two URLs with the prefix "episodeshowlinks/", one that takes a production_id and one that takes a show_id, the second with the name "episodeshowlinks_edit". There's no way for Django to distinguish between them, so Django will always call the first one and you will *never* get "showlink_id" in the kwargs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added `production_id` the following way: `href="{% url 'podfunnel:episodeshowlinks' production_id %}"` and still getting the exact error. Instead of getting an argument `'()'`, now I am getting `'('',)'`. I also tried as `production.id` and no success.

Comment: Well, you're not sending either production_id or production to the template context from the view, so they are blank.